Renewing Ukraine Passport at New York Consulate
I am trying to make an appointment for my mother (Connecticut resident) to renew her passport at the Ukrainian Consulate in NY. The process is a bit confusing.
After navigating the site I believe that the right starting point is here: https://go.mfa.gov.ua
I am able to choose United States for the country of residence and Consulate General of Ukraine in New York. I am then directed to his page:
https://go.mfa.gov.ua/services/25/68
I suppose I should click "Passport Actions" --> "Registration of a Foreign Passport". This directs me to the id.gov.ua site, which is very confusing. The options are (1) Electronic Signature, (2) Bank ID NBU and (3) Diaa.Signature.
I am not sure what this has to do this the process of registering for passport renewal visit, and all of these options seem to be dead ends (broken links or unintelligible).
Please help! I just want to make an appointment to renew a passport!

"Registration of a Foreign Passport" doesn't seem like the right thing.  If you select the embassy in Washington DC instead, one of the options is "Extension of the Passport", which doesn't appear when you choose the NYC consulate.  I didn't try to go further, but maybe it means that passport renewals have to go through the DC embassy rather than the NYC consulate.  Perhaps it can be done by mail rather than actually traveling to DC.

@NateEldredge is correct. If you select the Embassy in DC more passport options show up.

@NateEldredge, can you please post that as an answer.

But it takes you to the same id.gov.ua site that is confusing OP (and me), so it doesn't answer the main question which is how to use that site.

I dug down to this page which states in part "In the absence of an urgent need for the extension of the foreign passport, we suggest using the slot reserved by you to submit documents for the issuance of a biometric foreign passport."

I wonder what they mean by "foreign passport".  Normally that would mean "a non-Ukrainian passport" but that doesn't really make sense in context.  Does Ukraine have the concept of internal and external passports like some former Soviet states do or did?  Then maybe "foreign passport" means a Ukrainian external passport?  The English translations on that entire site are pretty awkward and not especially clear.

Liz, your original route of research online seems correct. I myself went the same route cause I was trying to help my friend to renew Ukrainian passport. I am myself Ukrainian and will need to do the same in a few years.
Basically, in order to set an appointment for renewing Ukrainian passport, Consulates and Embassies of Ukraine require you to be registed through the Ukrainian app "Diia". It's one of the options (3) Diaa.Signature. that you found. And then through this app you can set an appointment with the Consulate or embassy.
You can download Diia app on your phone and register by scanning your mother's biometric passport (if she has one)or through the Ukrainian bank account - whichever she has.
In US it is more complicated that if you were doing it from Ukraine.
Once you've registed through dia you go back to the website https://go.mfa.gov.ua, choose (3) Diaa.Signature and the website will give you a QR-Code you need to scan with your Diia app on your phone.
If for some reason you cannot register in Diia, you still can set an appointmment without it, but it is harder and longer. I tried and all the appointments are booked litterally a year ahead of something.
Try link https://usa.mfa.gov.ua/konsulski-pitannya/onlajn-zapis-na-konsulskij-prijom-e-cherga
You will see there are two options - to set an appointment without e-line (e-черга) and with one.
Honestly, I personally didn't finish trying to register in Diia because my Ukrainian passport is still valid for another 4 years. But if you persist down this path you can do it. You just need to be patient and persist.
You can call or email the consulate/embassy and ask them questions. You might need to call several times before they actually pick up (that's always the case for me) and be ready that they are not as helpful and talkative as US government staff. So be prepared to ask very presice questions.
Hope this helps. Good luck!
